# ClassNotFoundException after adding JAX-RS annotations (@Path etc.) in classes in Java

Tags: web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

I need some help with JAX-RS and Jersey in my multi module Java EE App.

I will start with describing my environment:

1. Java 8 (Java EE 7)
2. Maven 3.3.3
3. GlassFish 4.1.

After properly deploying on GlassFish there are such errors in logs:

```
[2016-02-08T14:06:10.302+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1454936770302] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class pl.com.softnet.rest.RestConfig, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pl.com.softnet.rest.RestConfig]]

[2016-02-08T14:06:10.304+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1454936770304] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class pl.com.softnet.rest.GraphConfig, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pl.com.softnet.rest.GraphConfig]]

[2016-02-08T14:06:10.304+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1454936770304] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class pl.com.softnet.rest.GraphConfig, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pl.com.softnet.rest.GraphConfig]]

[2016-02-08T14:06:10.304+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1454936770304] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class pl.com.softnet.rest.GraphConfig, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pl.com.softnet.rest.GraphConfig]]

[2016-02-08T14:06:10.305+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1454936770305] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class pl.com.softnet.rest.GraphConfig, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pl.com.softnet.rest.GraphConfig]]

[2016-02-08T14:06:10.305+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1454936770305] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class pl.com.softnet.rest.RestConfig, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pl.com.softnet.rest.RestConfig]]
```

Here is my poms dependency of Web Service module:

```
    <!-- JAVAEE API 7-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SERVLET-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
                <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.22</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.22</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- RICHAFACES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2-b04</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This is the resource class:

```
package pl.com.softnet.rest;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import pl.com.softnet.ejb3.localBeans.FSMAdministratorBean;
import pl.com.softnet.ejb3.localBeans.ModulBezpieczenstwaBean;
import pl.com.softnet.entity.ProcesyDef;
import pl.com.softnet.entity.Uzytkownik;
import pl.com.softnet.filters.TestFilter;
import pl.com.softnet.util.ServiceLocator;
import pl.com.softnet.util.XmlUtils;
import pl.com.softnet.wyjatki.ModyfikacjaProcesuException;

import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

@Path("config")
public class GraphConfig {

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response getMethod {

    }

    @POST
    @Path("{id}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response postMethod() {

    }

}
```

There is a Web Service class:

```
package pl.com.softnet.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationPath("/rest/*")
public class RestConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> myResources = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        myResources.add(GraphConfig.class);
        return myResources;
    }
}
```

My web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pl.com.softnet.rest.RestConfigr</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: `web.xml` >> `pl.com.softnet.rest.RestConfigr` extra 'r' at the end

Comment: It was only my bad, but it's not an good answer. My advice is -> when i remove JAX-RS annotations, i don't have any errors in logs...

Comment: Mine was a comment not an answer

Comment: @YouYou - sorry, i have a bad day :(

Comment: Never mind bro bad day is just a day that we learn something new ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enviroment :

- Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
- Apache Maven 3.0.3
- Glassfish 4.1 (build 13)

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.ceptro.measure</groupId>
    <artifactId>restfullexample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>restfullexample</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Class that extends Application

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package br.ceptro.measure.restfullexample;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

/**
 *
 * @author polianareis
 */
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("resources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }

    /**
     * Do not modify addRestResourceClasses() method.
     * It is automatically populated with
     * all resources defined in the project.
     * If required, comment out calling this method in getClasses().
     */
    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(br.ceptro.measure.restfullexample.OlaBrasilResource.class);
    }

}
```

Your REST WEb Services

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package br.ceptro.measure.restfullexample;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * REST Web Service
 *
 * @author polianareis
 */
@Path("ola-brasil")
public class OlaBrasilResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of OlaBrasilResource
     */
    public OlaBrasilResource() {
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of br.ceptro.measure.restfullexample.OlaBrasilResource
     * @return an instance of java.lang.String
     */
    @POST
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String postJson(String content) throws JSONException {

        JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject(content);
        String value = jSONObject.getString("value");

        return "Your web service works so well !!! ValueIs="+ value;
    }

    /**
     * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of OlaBrasilResource
     * @param content representation for the resource
     * @return an HTTP response with content of the updated or created resource.
     */
    @PUT
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public String putJson(String content) {
         return "Example PUT";
    }
}
```

You just need, clean and build. and deploy the war artifact in Glassfish 4.1

For test, you could use a REST Client in your navigator.

This is complete example and its works . See the image below:

[Testing your rest application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iED0L.png)

Answer (score 1):

In your web.xml you just need this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

Note that is important  the web-app version of web.xml

In your pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

And, you need a class that implements Application, but you don't need any Implementation. Just Like this is enough:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestConfig extends Application {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of SimetPersistence
     */
    public RestConfig() {
    }
}
```

and, your application:

```
@Path("config")
public class GraphConfig {

 public GraphConfig() {}

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response getMethod {
...
```

It, must work. =)

Comment: It's not good idea, because I'm using glassfish 4.1, and Jersey 1.x doesn't work on Servlet 3.x.

Comment: Oh, i have a restfull web services in glassfish 4.1.1 and its work for me.

Comment: I cant share the original code because  it is from my company, than i create a sample for you. I hope its work in your computer, because here is working well . See next answer :

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using servlet 3.0 or higher

From https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/2.0/deployment.html

> There are multiple deployment options for the class that implements
>   Application interface in the Servlet 3.0 container. For simple
>   deployments, no web.xml is needed at all. Instead, an @ApplicationPath
>   annotation can be used to annotate the user defined application class
>   and specify the the base resource URI of all application resources

First remove all related Jersey configuration from `web.xml`

Update your RestConfig to be :

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        packages("pl.com.softnet.rest");// This will scan for rest resources
    }      
}
```

The other approach is to use `web.xml` in that case remove `MyApplication` class

and update your `web.xml` to be like the following:

```
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>pl.com.softnet.rest</param-value>
      </init-param>
     </servlet>
    ...
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I hope that can work ! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work :( i did it as you wrote but my logs are having now one more warning with ClasNotFoundException for RestConfig

Comment: Did you use first approach or second one?

Comment: I used both of them.

Comment: Did your clean & build your project?

Comment: Sure, always before building I clean project :)

Comment: Check this : https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/374 this seems to be just a spurious warning

Comment: Does you application deploy if not is there logs left in the log? Because it seems that Jersey is now configured properly

Comment: The app deploys properly, but after deploying I see these warnings in logs.

Comment: @Redpike So ignore them as mentioned at last the link before the guys says that warning is a spurious at that case , What matter now is rest working?

Comment: I used other options and now I'm getting new error javax.ejb.NoSuchObjectLocalException: The EJB does not exist. So now it's a business logic of my app I think :) Thanks a lot for Your help :)!